can't iterate over array created in service - async issue?
I create an array of Items like this in my service:
items: IItem[] = [];
...
LoadItems() {
        this.GetItems().subscribe((res) => {
            // console.log(res);
            if (res.status == 200 && res.body.data != undefined) {
                var data = res.body.data;
                this.items.push({
                        Id: data[i].id,
                        IsBlue: data[i].isBlue, //this is a bool
                    });
                }    
            }
            // console.log(this.items.length);
        });
    }

This is called in ngOnInIt in my app.component.ts file. Then I want to iterate over this array of Items like so in item.component.ts:
GetBlueItems(items: IItem[]) {
    var blueitems: IItem[] = [];
    console.log(items); //this returns the array correctly

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].isBlue) {
            blueitems.push(items[i]);  
        }
    }

But it just never iterates over the array. When I do console.log(items.length) it returns 0, which confuses me because console.log(items) shows that the array is not empty.
I've tried printing the length of the array within the subscribe block and it does return the length correctly, so I assume it's an issue with synchronization? But then I still don't understand why the console would print this without issue:
0: {Id: 1, IsBlue: false }
1: {Id: 2, IsBlue: true }
length: 2

I've also tried doing a forEach loop over the array, but it won't iterate with that either:
items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.isBlue) {
        blueitems.push(item);  
    }
});

I would like to be able to use this array outside of the subscribe block if that even is the issue. I don't need it to be updated constantly.
ETA: The reason I want to be able to use the array outside of the subscribe block is because I want to display the information in html, use it in different functions such as adding items to a shopping cart & checking out, etc. It seems difficult to do if I have to confine my use of the array to within the subscribe block.

Your for loop won’t work - shoul be items[i].isBlue, not item.isBlue. Probably a copy to question issue.

Add console logging to the forEach loop before the condition: console.log(‘item.isblue’, item.isBlue). Perhaps isBlue is ‘true’ rather than true.

@JohnWilliams - ah, you're right; but it was just a copy issue on this post. Fixed that.
I actually did add console logging inside the loop right before the if block, and it just never goes inside there at all.

Mysterious. Can you add the code for ngOnInIt with all the console.log. I am looking for sync stuff: wait and then type stuff.

I would use RxJS Streams to solve this Problem, i think there is no need to subscribe inside a service. I would just pass the Observable. So Components an use async pipe or signals to pass data to templates.
interface IItem {
  IsBlue: boolean;
  Id: number;
}

const fakeResponseData: IItem[] = [
  {
    Id: -1,
    IsBlue: true
  },
  {
    Id: 0,
    IsBlue: false
  }
]

const fakeResponse: HttpResponse<IItem[]> = new HttpResponse({
  body: fakeResponseData,
  status: 200,
})

const fakeRequqest = of(fakeResponse);

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  private item$: Observable<IItem[]>;

  LoadItems(): Observable<IItem[]> {
    if (!this.item$) {
      this.item$ = fakeRequqest.pipe(
        map(response => response.body),
        filter((response): response is IItem[] => response !== null && response !== undefined),
        shareReplay() // shareReplay is optional, it depends on your use case, now we have a little cache
      );
    }
    return this.item$
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  template: `<ul><li *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">{{item.IsBlue}}</li></ul>`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe]
}) 
export class myComponent{

  private readonly myService = inject(MyService);

  protected readonly items$ = this.myService.LoadItems().pipe(
    map(items=> items.filter(item => item.IsBlue))
  )

  /** example angular 17+ with signals 
    protected readonly blueItems = toSignal(
      this.myService.LoadItems().pipe(map(items=> items.filter(item => item.IsBlue)))
    );

    // in template
    @for (item of blueItems(); track item.id) {
      {{item.IsBlue}}
    }
  */
}


Your first code block is missing the forEach loop that loads the data
    items: IItem[] = [];
    blueitems: IItem[] = [];
    ...
    LoadItems() {
        this.GetItems().subscribe((res) => {
            // console.log(res);
            if (res.status == 200 && res.body.data != undefined) {
                var data = res.body.data;
                data.forEach((item: any, i: number) => {
                    this.items.push({
                        Id: item[i].id,
                        IsBlue: item[i].isBlue, //this is a bool
                    });
                });
                }    
            }
            // console.log(this.items.length);
            this.getBlueItems(this.items);
        });
    }

Then call this function with the forEach loop.
GetBlueItems(items: IItem[]) {
    console.log(items); //this returns the array correctly

    items.forEach(item => {
        if (item.isBlue) {
            this.blueitems.push(item);  
        }
    });
}


this works for the loop, but then I can't use the blueitems array outside of the subscribe block either. i want to use it to display information to the user.

@necrophade add that logic also inside the subscribe, anyway blue items is created using the data inside the subscribe

Is that the only possible option? It seems a little unweildy. I want to be able to use this data for a lot of different things, is there really no way to access it outside of the subscribe block?

@necrophade When it comes to observables, this is the method. But if its signals it totally different but you need the latest version of angular for that 17+

@necrophade its also unclear what you mean by many things, because maybe there is a simpler way to do the many things instead of trying to bypass the subscribe!

so the items are purchasable and displayed on a table in html. I think I need the data outside of subscribe for a user to be able to add items to a cart, choose options, edit them... I am not even sure how to display async items in the html table honestly.

@necrophade you can use async pipe to do this, if you want to share data between component use a service to store this.items

this.items is in a service, the entire first code block is. Is that not what you mean by "use a service to store this.items"?

@necrophade You can use a getter to access the service property in the HTML, get items() { return this.service.items } then do whatever you want to this.items on the component and it will reflect on the service
